# Publishing ClickOnce application with NANT script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, clickonce, nant, mage

My `WPF` application is deployed with `ClickOnce`.

In `Visual Studio` I open "`Project properties / Publish`".

There I have:

- Publish location
- Publish URL
- Version
- Signature

The problem is, that I have to publish every version for test and production.
The difference between them are properties `publish location` and `publish URL`. Currently I have to execute the process twice, while changing the values before publishing for production.

So the result of pressing publish is a folder containing folder "`ApplicationFiles`", the `application manifest` file and a `setup.exe`.

**Then i decided to automate this process using NANT.**

I build/publish the application first for testing (here i set the .csproj file location, publish folder and application varsion)

```
<target name="BuildTestApplication" depends="Clean" description="Build">
  <echo message="Building..." />    
  <exec program="${msbuildExe}" workingdir="." verbose="true">
    <arg value="${projectFile}" />
    <arg value="/target:Clean;Publish" />
    <arg value="/p:PublishDir=${testPublishFolder}" />
    <arg value="/p:ApplicationVersion=${version}" />
    <arg value="/p:Publisher=&quot;${publisherName}&quot;" />
  </exec>
  <echo message="Built" />
</target>
```

With this I found out that build does not set the publisher. Plus I need to change the provider URL, since the application is also installed via internet (different URLs for test and production). So i did:

```
<target name="UpdateTestApplication" depends="BuildTestApplication" description="Update">
  <echo message="Updating..." />    
  <exec program="${mageExe}" workingdir="." verbose="true">
    <arg value="-Update" />
    <arg value="${testPublishFolder}/EdpClient.application" />
    <arg value="-ProviderUrl" />
    <arg value="&quot;${testPublishUrl}&quot;" />
    <arg value="-Publisher" />
    <arg value="&quot;${publisherName}&quot;" />
  </exec>
  <echo message="Updated" />
</target>
```

With this I have updated the `application manifest` file with correct values (`Publisher` and `ProviderUrl`)...

I do the same for production build, meaning i build the application to another folder and update it with different `ProviderUrl` and add `Publisher`, since it has to be included in every `mage` update...

Now the problem is with **`setup.exe`** file. 
`Setup.exe` is generated at build and it takes the values from the `.csproj` file.

Considering all of the above I have three issues:

**1.**
Is there a way of building the application with the correct parameters, so the `setup.exe` would contain the correct values?

**2.**
Also how would I update Assembly information (parameter version) before build? When publishing from `VS` i need to update it on "`Probject properties / Application / Assembly Information`"

**3.**
I noticed that when Publishing from `VS` the application manifest file is also generated in the "`Application Files`" folder, while publishing with `MSBUILD` it is not. Why is that?

Thank you in advance and best regards, no9

**EDIT:**

I fixed the problem **#2** like so:

```
<!--UPDATE ASSEMBLY INFORMATION BEFORE BUILD-->
  <target name="UpdateAssemblyInfo">
    <asminfo output="${assemblyInfoFile}" language="CSharp">
      <imports>
        <import namespace="System" />
        <import namespace="System.Reflection" />
        <import namespace="System.Resources" />
        <import namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" />
        <import namespace="System.Runtime.InteropServices" />
        <import namespace="System.Windows" />
      </imports>
      <attributes>
        <attribute type="AssemblyTitleAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyDescriptionAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyConfigurationAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyCompanyAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyProductAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyVersionAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyFileVersionAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyCopyrightAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyTrademarkAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="AssemblyCultureAttribute" value="some value" />
        <attribute type="CLSCompliantAttribute" value="boolean value" />
        <attribute type="ComVisibleAttribute" value="boolean value" />
      </attributes>
    </asminfo>
    <echo file="${assemblyInfoFile}" append="true">
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// or application resource dictionaries)
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
    </echo>
    <echo message="Updated" />
  </target>
```

Meaning I override `Assembly.info` file before build and add relevant values.

And the problem `#3` like so:

```
   <!--COPY APPLICATION MANIFEST TO APPLICATIONFILES FOLDER-->
      <target name="CopyTestApplicationManifestToApplicationFilesFolder"     depends="Dependency target name" description="Update">
      <echo message="Copying..." />
      <copy 
        file="source file"
        tofile="target file" />
       <echo message="Copied" />
     </target>
```

Comment: Would be calling a console application before building and using a console application for the building itself be a possible solution for you? Or has it to be NANT?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create tasks that properly generated the assets you mentioned in your question (setup.exe,application folder, etc.) without having to explicitly sign manifest.

the "clean_and_publish_application" task does the following

1. Clean the project
2. Rebuild the project
3. Publish the project **Here i provide several parameters specifying my publish url, BootstrapperSDKPath,Application Version, and Application Revision

   ```
   <target name="clean_and_publish_application" description="Build the application.">
   <echo message="Clean the build directory"/>
   <msbuild project ="${src.dir}\${target.assembly.name}.csproj">
            <arg value="/property:Configuration=Debug;outdir=bin\Debug" />
            <arg value="/t:clean" />
    </msbuild>
    <echo message="Rebuild the application"/>
    <msbuild project ="${src.dir}\${target.assembly.name}.csproj">
    <arg value="/property:Configuration=Debug;outdir=bin\Debug" />
    <arg value="/t:rebuild" />
   </msbuild>
   <echo message="Publish the application"/>
   <msbuild project ="${src.dir}\${target.assembly.name}.csproj">
   <arg value="/p:publishurl=${publish.url};
   GenerateBootstrapperSdkPath=
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft  SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\;
   ApplicationVersion=${app.version};
   ApplicationRevision=${app.revision}" />
   <arg value="/t:publish" />
   </msbuild>
   </target>
   ```

The BootstrapperSdkPath property is required for the creation of the setup.exe file. I hard coded the location because it doesn't change. MSBuild is looking for a setup.bin file within that directory.

The ApplicationVersion property is formatted as for example 2.0.0.%2a

The ApplicationRevision property is formatted as a number for example 24 (these values are the Publish Version we see in visual studio. I never actually update the AssemplyInfo.cs file at all.)

Any property you see listed in the .csproj file can be passed as an argument for msbuild. I found this documentation very helpful  [MSBuild Command-Line Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

The above task does everything you need EXCEPT actually copy the files to your publish url (Still looking for the answer for this). So I just manually copy all the files from the app.config directory the publish creates

```
<target name="copy_src">
<echo message="Copying app.config folder"/>
    <copy todir="${publish.url}" overwrite="true"  failonerror="true">
        <fileset basedir="${src.dir}\${app.config.location}">
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

I'm running these scripts in Team City. Because I used the publish target, I didn't have to worry about signing any manifests. Also, I use the msbuild task from the NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll which you can download here [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/)